# AngularJS custom table directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have made a table with AngularJS all is working good pagination and sorting but i want to make it as a component so that in other pages it can be used. Right now i have made a factory which calls my API and controller and server side pagination is also implemented.
Now what should be the way of making table as a tag like

Comment: implement your table as a directive?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate your component and behaviours into an [Angular Directive.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Directives are one of the key parts of AngularJS, you really need to read up on how they work, then creating a table directive becomes simple. [Try starting here, it's a great introduction.](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look how the table #ngtasty is implemented.
Docs : http://zizzamia.com/ng-tasty/
Table directive : https://github.com/Zizzamia/ng-tasty/blob/master/src/table/table.js